# Getting round Button With User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: xcode, swift

First i'm working with swift . Second i have made the CAlayer extension

```
extension CALayer
{
    func borderUIColor() -> UIColor? {
        return borderColor != nil ? UIColor(CGColor: borderColor!) : nil
    }

    func setBorderUIColor(color: UIColor) {
        borderColor = color.CGColor
    }
}
```

and here are the results with this attributes

[image]

> results:

[image]

I get those corner kind of spikes which of the layers properties can help me. Do I Shift bounds or deal with content or something.

Comment: Can you try making sure that clip subviews checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your extension methods with a computed property, like so:

```
extension CALayer
{
    var borderUIColor(): UIColor? {
        get {
            return borderColor
        }

        set {
            borderColor = borderUIColor
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you really don't need an extension at all--just use the layer's `borderColor`. Replace your `layer.borderUIColor` runtime attribute with `layer.borderColor`, and, for best effect, add `layer.masksToBounds` as `true`.

Comment: I can't use the layer.borderColor straight way it's off unsupported type by IB that's what i have read and the border color using this extension works just that i don't want that edge spikes that is visible

Comment: `layer.borderColor` is a `CGColor`, not a `UIColor`, which is maybe what you meant by an "unsupported type". But when you use it in a user-defined runtime property, you can use the color picker just fine.

Comment: Thank you . the layer.masksToBounds worked , i'll learn what it means .and so does the layer.borderColor worked i removed the extension .

Comment: `masksToBounds` tells the view not to render any content that lies outside of the border.